# order json array for equal values

Tags: php, arrays, json

hello i have json file which contain like this data

```
{
    "data": [

        {
            "SN": "210477",
            "name": "jane",
            "stdcode": "446515",
            "total": 611
        },
        {

            "SN": "210474",
            "name": "JOHN doe",
            "stdcode": "446512",
            "total": 610
        },
        {
            "SN": "210475",
            "name": "smith doe",
            "stdcode": "446513",
            "total": 610
        },
        {
            "SN": "210476",
            "name": "omar",
            "stdcode": "446514",
            "total": 610
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see there is duplicate in total in the last three data in total which is 610
i want to order this data according to "total" so it be printed like this

```
1.jane
2.JOHN doe
2.smith doe
2.omar
```

i have this code that order it but this not what i want

```
<?php
$get_records =  @file_get_contents('./result.json',true);
$decode_records = json_decode($get_records);
$data = $decode_records->data;

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->total > $b->total ? -1 : 1;
});

for($x=0;$x<=count($data);$x++){
    echo $x+1 .".".$data[$x]->name;
}

?>
```

the code output

```
1.jane
2.JOHN doe
3.smith doe
4.omar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the total has changed, and don't increment the rank if not.

```
$rank = 0;
$last_total = null;
foreach ($data as $d) {
    if ($d->total !== $last_total) {
        $rank++;
        $last_total = $d->total;
    }
    echo "$rank. {$data->name}<br>";
}
```

Note that this means that the next index after all the duplicates will be ranked #3. If you want it to jump to 5 you need to use the array index as well.

```
$last_total = null;
foreach ($data as $i => $d) {
    if ($d->total !== $last_rank) {
        $rank = $i+1;
        $last_total = $d->total;
    }
    echo "$rank. {$data->name}<br>";
}
```

Comment: the first one works but after i delete some mistakes and update it to fit my code                              $rank = 0;
$last_total = 0;

for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++){

  if ($data[$x]->total !== $last_total) {
          $rank++;
          $last_total = $data[$x]->total;
      }
echo $rank ."- "."(".$data[$x]->name." ) (".$data[$x]->SN.")  = ".$data[$x]->total ."<br>";
}

Comment: Why do you prefer a `for` loop instead of `foreach`? It just makes the code more verbose because you have to keep writing `$data[$x]`.